# Хочу сделать так, чтобы определенные строки таблицы окрашивались в цвета

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

У меня есть вот такая форма:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вкратце, она реализует механизм черного и белого списков, в таблице слева загружается список всех программ из реестра, а справа в двух вкладках программы, входящие в белый и черный списки соответственно, когда программа добавляется в какой-либо список то она убирается из левой таблицы и появляется в правой, а если удаляется из списка то наоборот.
И я хочу ее немного отполировать, а именно, сделать так, чтобы при загрузке первой вкладки с надписью, как на фото, программы которые находятся в белом списке выделялись зеленым, а те которые находятся в черном - красном. Как это реализовать?

Comment: [CellFormatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Зачем эта третья вкладка вообще? Сделайте 2, какая включена, туда и перемещайте элемент. И кнопки 2, а не 4 понадобится.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridcolumnstyle

Comment: @aepot, это дополнение, за которое я получу оценку выше